# Show that $x_{t},y_{t}$ are jointly stationary, and interpretation of CAcovF, $\gamma_{XY}(h)$ not being symmetric for lags $h$

Tags: time-series, expected-value, covariance, white-noise

Consider two white noise processes $(w_{t})_{t}$~$WN(0,\sigma_{w}^{2})$ and $(u_{t})_{t}$~$WN(0,\sigma_{u}^{2})$ that are also independent of each other such that

$y_{t}=w_{t}-\theta w_{t-1}+u_{t}$ and also $x_{t}=w_{t}$, where $\theta$ is some constant.

Evaluate the Cross-Covariation function $\gamma_{XY}(h)$ for $h=0,+1,-1,....$ and then show that $x_{t}$ and $y_{t}$ are jointly stationary.

My steps:

Let $h \in \mathbb Z$, then $\gamma_{XY}(h)=Cov(x_{t+h},y_{t})=Cov(w_{t+h},w_{t}-\theta w_{t-1}+u_{t})=Cov(w_{t+h},w_{t})-\theta Cov(w_{t+h},w_{t-1})$

Simply plugging in $h$, we realize that $\gamma_{XY}(h)=\sigma_{w}^{2}$ if $h=0$ and $\gamma_{XY}(h)=-\theta\sigma_{w}^{2}$ if $h=-1$. Furthermore, $\gamma_{XY}(h)=0$ for any other $h$.

Clearly, the $\gamma_{XY}(h)$ is time-independent, so I could assume that it is jointly stationary. Is this correct? I find it quite peculiar that there is no symmetry around the lags. Is there any interpretation, anecdote (no proof etc.) as to why we obtain symmetry around lags for the autocovariance function but not necessarily for the cross-covariance function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The computations look correct.

There's no such "symmetry" in the crosscovariance function because they don't measure the same effect at all:

- $h=1$ is the effect of today's $Y$ on tomorrow's $X$
- $h=-1$ is the effect of today's $X$ on tomorrow's $Y$

Here, $X_t$ is a predictor of $Y_{t+1}$, but $Y_t$ contains no information about $X_{t+1}$ at all. You can consider $X$ as a "leading indicator" of $Y$, but the reverse is not true. This occurs frequently in certain application domains, and is the type of relationship covered by the concept of Granger causality.

An even easier example is to take $Y_t = w_t$ and $X_t = w_{t-1}$. Then, knowing $Y_t$ you can predict $X_{t+1} = Y_t$ exactly, but knowing $X_t$ tells you nothing about $Y_{t+1}$ since the $w_t$ are independent.

I know you said no proofs, but I think it's illuminating: the symmetry for the autocovariance function comes straight from its definition. Since it doesn't depend on $t$, you can shift both indexes by the same amount:

$$\gamma_X(h) = \text{cov}(X_{t+h}, X_t) = \text{cov}(X_t,X_{t-h}) = \text{cov}(X_{t-h},X_t) = \gamma_X(-h)$$

For the cross-covariance, it's slightly different:

$$\gamma_{XY}(h) = \text{cov}(X_{t+h}, Y_t) = \text{cov}(X_t,Y_{t-h}) = \text{cov}(Y_{t-h},X_t) = \gamma_{YX}(-h)$$

That is, if you flip the sign of $h$, you have to reverse $X$ and $Y$. If $X=Y$, like in the autocovariance function, it makes no difference.